# Function for generating multiple line charts for all variables in a dataframe for different groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 106 weeks data for 5 different LOB (Line of Business). The variables are Traffic, Spend, Clicks, etc. In total there will be 106*5 = 530 rows.

Dataframe looks like:

```
LOB Week Traffic Spend Clicks
A   1   34  12  5
A   2   37  32  6
A   3   41  57  7
A   4   52  42  12
A   5   27  37  8

 ... 106 weeks
B...106 weeks
C...106 weeks
D...106 weeks


E   1   43  22  12
E   2   65  16  14
E   3   76  18  9
E   4   25  14  11
E   5   53  15  15
... 106 weeks
```

I want to generate line chart for Traffic for all the 5 different LOB on the same chart, similarly for other metrics also. For this I have written a function but it is not doing what I want.

Code:

```
for ( i in seq(1,length( data),1) ) plot(data[,i],ylab=names(data[i]),type="l", col = "red", xlab = "Week", main = "")
```

Kindly suggest me how this can be done.

Comment: Can you add in a description of what you want this to look like? Each LOB has its own panel of each metric, or each metric has a panel showing lines for each LOB, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ggplot2` :

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Week, y = Traffic, color = LOB)) +
geom_line()
```

Please try to submit a toy example of your data so we can reproduce the code. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Edit: as suggested by @Axeman, you may want to plot all metrics together. Here is his solution for visibility:

```
d <- gather(data, metric, value, -Week, -LOB)
ggplot(d, aes(Week, value, color = LOB)) + 
geom_line() + 
facet_wrap(~metric, scales = 'free_y')
```

Comment: Possibly OP wants to plot the different metrics too. One could do `d <- gather(data, metric, value, -Week, -LOB); ggplot(d, aes(Week, value, color = LOB)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~metric, scales = 'free_y')`